# Perimeter of a parallelogram just with the area

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, area

The area of a parallelogram is $2019^{2019}$ square unit. What is the perimeter of this parallelogram?
I know the basic formula but could not break down $2019^{2019}$, and connect that to the perimeter.
Thanks!

Comment: Even for a rectangle it's easy to see that the area does not determine the perimeter.  Is there part of the problem you're not telling us?

Comment: @RobertIsrael unfortunately no..there is no other part of this problem.

Comment: I believe the tricks lies here is to break down $2019^{2019}$, and then we can use the formula to find the perimeter $P=2a+2\frac{A}{h}$, where $a$ is base, $A$ is area, $h$ is height. But I could be wrong.

Comment: You are wrong.  The area is $a h$.  The perimeter is $2a + 2b$ where $b$ is the other side.  $b = h = A/a$ if the parallelogram is a rectangle, but not otherwise.

Comment: And there is no possibility of "breaking down" unless you have other information.

Comment: Thank you Professor Israel for your help. I appreciate that. This is off topic, but could you suggest me a good geometry book for high school level? @RobertIsrael

Comment: @J.Joey Do you want to cover the whole universe with your biggy parallelogram? Then let its area be $\infty$.  There may be lack of information about how you construct your parallelogram and length of that figure.

Comment: Did the question mention anything else? Does the parallelogram have any integer sides? Do its vertices lie on lattice points?

Comment: @J.Joey If you're looking for a good geometry book have a look at Evan Chen's 'Euclidean Geometry in Mathematical Olympiads. You can also have a look here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Olympiad_books

Comment: Maybe all the side lengths have to be integers?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

> What can you tell about these parallelograms? Do they have the same area? And equal perimeter? Why?